# NHibernate MySqlException

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, database-connection

**I am trying use NHibernate to my MySQL but I have still issue with connection on my localhost database.**

Exeptions:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
  Source=MySql.Data
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare()
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper)
   at NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at TestE.Model.NHibernateHelper.get_Session() in C:\Users\hajek\source\repos\TestE\TestE\NHibernateHelper.cs:line 24
   at TestE.Dao.DaoBase1..ctor() in C:\Users\hajek\source\repos\TestE\TestE\Dao\DaoBase.cs:line 20
   at TestE.Dao.ItemDao..ctor() in C:\Users\hajek\source\repos\TestE\TestE\Dao\ItemDao.cs:line 13
   at TestE.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\hajek\source\repos\TestE\TestE\Program.cs:line 16
Inner Exception 1:
WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException: No handle of the given name exists.
```

Code:

```
namespace TestE.Model
{
    public class NHibernateHelper
    {
        private static ISessionFactory factory;
        private static MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        public static ISession Session
        {
            get
            {
                if (factory == null)
                {
                    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
                    factory = cfg.Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").BuildSessionFactory();

                }

                return factory.OpenSession();
            }
        }



    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
This template was written to work with NHibernate.Test.
Copy the template to your NHibernate.Test project folder and rename it in hibernate.cfg.xml and change it 
for your own use before compile tests in VisualStudio.
-->
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="TestE">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Database=todo_list;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=root;
      Protocol=memory;Old Guids=True;
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Configuration is located in `~/bin/debug` and Nhibernate can see it but still can not connect to database.

----- Sorry for my English Language.------

Answer (score 0):

By default, shared memory [is not enabled](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_shared-memory) on Windows. This may be why your connection is failing.

Remove `Protocol=memory;` from your connection string to use a regular TCP/IP connection.